# Creating a Patch with TFS

Tags: version-control, tfs, patch

Creating a patch is very easy in SubVersion, With Tortoise, you right-click and select Create Patch. But for the life of me, I can't find this functionality in TFS. Is this possible?

If not, what's the standard way to submit patches in open source TFS hosted projects (a la CodePlex)?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
tf diff /shelveset:shelveset /format:unified
```

**Edit:** This writes to standard output.  You can pipe the output to a file.

For more options, see [Difference Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fd7dc73%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?
1. How would you apply this patch?
2. Also, if the project is read-only to the patcher, he can't create a shelveset, can he?

Comment: There's a standard UNIX program called "patch" that applies unified diffs to source trees. I'm sure you could find a Windows implementation, or you could use Cygwin.

Comment: @Doron this displays all differences between the shelveset and the current workspace folder in a format similar to: http://hg.shrinkrays.net/spruce/changeset/0d00e3c15e2c/raw/spruce-0d00e3c15e2c.diff

Comment: How do you pipe `|` to a file? I thought you had to redirect `>` to a file.

Comment: If you haven't done this before: In the Start menu, drill down to Visual Studio, Tools, Command Prompt. Then cd to a folder somewhere in the local tree of the workspace, e.g. c:\build\myProject\src

Answer (score 2):

Because TFS doesn't natively support patch files, the most common thing I see people do on CodePlex is simply zip the modified files and upload the zip.  The project coordinator then does a diff against their own checkout.

However since CodePlex also supports TortoiseSVN, more and more people are using that to create their patch files.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post about a similar issue where I used the TF.exe command and 7Zip to [create a TFS patch file](http://codeblog.theg2.net/2014/09/create-tfs-patch-file-with-pending.html) that could then be applied on another TFS server or workspace. I posted the the Powershell scripts at [Github](https://github.com/gbrayut/CodeBlog/tree/master/20140914_TFS), which can be used to Zip up any pending changes on one workspace and then apply them to a different server. It would have to be modified to use a changeset instead of pending changes, but that shouldn't be too difficult to accomplish.

Comment: This script uses the whole file, not the diffed lines. More of a controlled xcopy